# Retrieving mapping entity class name from table name in JPA in runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

How to retrieve mapping entity class name from table name in JPA in runtime?

Following line

```
entityClass.getAnnotation(Table.class).name()
```

returns the table name. Is the opposite also possible in ORM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574133/how-to-retrieve-an-entity-in-jpa-by-table-name-at-runtime

Comment: All depends on whether you are using annotations or XML metadata. Highly unlikely you'll get anywhere though without making use of internal APIs of your JPA provider